# how to round numbers and decimals in 1 function

Tags: php

I want to be able to round number (up or down) to remove the last 3 digits

EG

> I want 4500489 to =4500
>
> I want 34500489 to =34500

I need to do this with the same code/function

i have tried both the below

```
$value = round($value, 4);


$value = sprintf('4f', $value);
```

Neither work (i'm not sure if i am understanding how to use both the above right though!)

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Those numbers are already integers... you cannot round them. You want to divide by 1000 first, no?

Comment: What do you mean by 'one function'? You can create your own function and include as many lines and other functions as you need, can you not?

Comment: @qwertynl, `round` could round to any digit position. Try: round($4500489, -3)

Answer (score 2):

Just divide and round.

```
$value = 4500489;
echo round($value/1000); // 4500
```

Remeber that you could round to any digit position

```
echo round($value, -3); // 4500000
```

[Round](http://php.net/round)